# Will this query generate distinct random numbers in Mysql?

Tags: mysql, random

I have written the following query in Mysql:

```
SELECT distinct LPAD(FLOOR(RAND() * 999999999),9,0) AS random_num
FROM test;
```

If I have say 100000 records in my table **test**, then, will this query always give me 100000 **distinct** numbers? If not, why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is not always because the result of your query will be only the distinct values of your random numbers so if you generate the same random number 2 times, that number will appear only 1 time (you will lose 1 record).